# robot test case: for loop does not work

Tags: robotframework

I have following codes, some of them work but...(These sections are in 1 file and consecutive, split for clarification)

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation   documentation for this test suite
...             requires command line variables: IP

resource    resource/applicationcontrol.robot
resource    resource/clientmgr.robot

Suite Setup    applicationcontrol.Open connections
Suite Teardown    Close connections
Test Setup    Exit Current Running Apps

*** Variables ***
@{apps}    1stapp    2ndapp    3rdapp    4thapp
```

=====================================================

```
*** Keywords ***
App For Port    [Arguments]    ${app}
    :for    ${port_num}    IN    1    2
    \    applicationcontrol.Launch application    ${app}    ${port_num}
    \    ${status}    Run Keyword And Return Status    Check launching status    ${app}    ${port_num}
    \    Continue For Loop If    '${status}'=='False'
    \    Run Keyword If    '${status}'=='True'   Add Success 
    \    Exit For Loop                       <--Line in question
```

**Q: `Exit For Loop` exits the most enclosing For loop or all nesting For Loops?**

======================================================

```
Add Success
    ${success_num}    Evaluate    ${success_num} + 1

Ratio Statistics
    ${fail_num}    Evaluate    ${total_num} - ${success_num}
    Log    Total: ${total_num}, Failed: <p style="color:red">${fail_num}</p>    HTML

Exit Current Running Apps
    :for    ${port_num}    IN    1    2
    \    Exit application    ${port_num}
    \    Check exit status   ${port_num}        <--Line in question
```

**Q: `Check exit status   ${port_num}`   gets executed only for 1st loop...don't understand why**

======================================================

```
*** Test Cases ***
Launch and exit multiple apps    [Arguments]    @{apps}
    ${temp}    Get Length    ${apps}
    Set Test Variable    ${total_num}    ${temp}
    Set Test Variable    ${success_num}    0
    :for    ${app}    IN    @{apps}           <--Line in question
    \    App For Port    ${app}
    \    Exit Current Running Apps
    Ratio Statistics                         <--Line in question
```

**Q: `:for  ${app}    IN    @{apps}`     This For Loop should have executed 4 times, but only executed for 1 time.**

**Q: `Ratio Statistics`  never gets executed. How can I get it executed?**

I cannot find answers on internet or User's Guide. Thanks in advance.

*Additional:
resource/applicationcontrol.robot:*

```
Exit application    [Arguments]    ${PORT}
    ${RUNNING_RESPONSE}    send cmd    appsvc    get_apps
    ${RUNNING_APPS}    response parameter    ${RUNNING_RESPONSE}
    Pass Execution If    '${RUNNING_APPS}' == '${None}'    No app running on ${PORT}
    ${TARGET_APP}    get target application    ${RUNNING_APPS}    ${PORT}   
    send cmd    appsvc      exit_app    ${TARGET_APP}
```

Comment: We cant' run the tests in your question. Please create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, I found the answer.

In resource/applicationcontrol.robot:

```
Exit application    [Arguments]    ${PORT}
    ${RUNNING_RESPONSE}    send cmd    appsvc    get_apps
    ${RUNNING_APPS}    response parameter    ${RUNNING_RESPONSE}
    Pass Execution If    '${RUNNING_APPS}' == '${None}'    No app running on ${PORT}
    ${TARGET_APP}    get target application    ${RUNNING_APPS}    ${PORT}   
    send cmd    appsvc      exit_app    ${TARGET_APP}
```

The `Pass Execution If`  statement exits current **test case** in question instead of **the rest of that keyword**, which is what I want it to be.

**So my solution** is putting the rest of this keyword into a new 'helper' keyword and using `Run Keyword Unless` instead to invoke the new keyword.

Answer (score 0):

> Exit For Loop exits the most enclosing For loop or all nesting For Loops?
>   Real nested for loops don't exist in Robot.
>   You can just have a loop that calls a keyword that has a loop.
>   Anyway, "Exit For Loop" exist the current loop (most enclosing if you want)
>
> Check exit status   ${port_num} gets executed only for 1st 
>   for  ${app}    IN    @{apps} This For Loop should have executed 4 times
>   Ratio Statistics never gets executed. How can I get it executed?We don't have enough information to help you on those questions. Yes, it should work the way you describe... See Brian's comment.